# Force JavaScript to fire up new controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Using VS 2013 in VB, MVC-5:
This question pertains to simply calling a Controller method, and passing along a string variable, from View #1 (within JavaScript code).

The Controller should then permanently call View #2. The key is I think using AJAX returns to the function within View #1?

**Details:**

I've captured a left-click event within the Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler and I want to pass the determined value (a string) to a Controller method. I then want the Controller method to call up a new View.

In theory, my question has nothing to do with Cesium, except that it fires from within the click-event handler.

Here's the JavaScript code within the 1st View:

```js
var leftClickHandler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);

leftClickHandler.setInputAction(function (action) {
    //reset visibility of selectionIndicator and infoBox
    viewer.selectionIndicator.viewModel.selectionIndicatorElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-infoBox')[0].style.visibility = "visible";

    var pickedObject = viewer.scene.pick(action.position);
    //don't do anything if we didn't click on an object
    if (!Cesium.defined(pickedObject)) { return; }

    //don't do anything if it's not the entity we care about
    //if (entity !== pickedObject.id) { return; }

    //if this is the entity we care about, hide the selectionIndicator and infoBox
    viewer.selectionIndicator.viewModel.selectionIndicatorElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-infoBox')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";

    var myEntity = pickedObject.id;
    //alert('Picked: ' + myEntity.name);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("JobSelected", "Earth")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        data: myEntity.name,
        success: function () {
            alert("okay!");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown + jqXHR);
        }
    });
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

And here's my Controller Action Method that I want to invoke from the 1st View (or similar--TBD):

```
<HttpPost>
Public Function JobSelected(jobSpec As String) As ActionResult
    Dim result = edRepository.GetEarthDataByJobNumber(jobSpec).ToList()

    Return RedirectToActionPermanent("EarthData2", result)
End Function
```

I've been stuck on this for two days. And I've tried everything I could find, including using Ajax (obviously) but to no avail.

Summary:

I've captured a left-click event which yields a specific job name. I'd like to pass that job name into a new controller action and have that action fire up a new View (whose model contains details of that specific job).

My problem lies in simply calling the controller method, passing along the one single variable (string), and then having the method call up a new view.

**New Information:**
I've replaced the Ajax call with the following code in the View:

```js
            var myEntity = pickedObject.id;
            //alert("'" + myEntity.name + "'");

            var myUrl = '@Url.Action("JobSelected", "Earth")';
            var newUrl = myUrl + '?=' + myEntity.name.replace(/ /g, "");
            var newUrl2 = newUrl.replace("HTI#", "");
            var newUrl3 = newUrl2.substr(0, newUrl2.indexOf("-"));

            window.location.replace(newUrl3);
```

Most of which is some cleanup of the myEntity.name string that is returned earlier.

Okay, so this posts GREAT (thanks for the assistance), but now I just cannot seem to get my Controller to be able to use the Query that's now in the hyperlink.  In other words, the hyperlink now shows;
**../Earth/JobSelected?=1511033**
But whatever I do, I cannot seem to be able to extract the 1511033 that's in the hyperlink.  I've tried:

```
            Dim q As String = Request.Url.Query
```

This is my current Controller Action method;

```
        <ActionName("JobSelected")>
    Function JobSelected() As ActionResult
        Dim q As String = Request.Url.Query
        Dim result = edRepository.GetEarthDataByHtiJobNumber(q).ToList()

        'The following works fine, so my issue is with obtaining the value (q) to be passed...
        'Dim result = edRepository.GetEarthDataByHtiJobNumber("1503069").ToList()

        Return View("EarthData2", result)
    End Function
```

But that's not working.  I get an exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Any advice?

**Well, I found the answers I needed.  The following works;**
**JavaScript code:**

```js
            var myEntity = pickedObject.id;
            //alert("'" + myEntity.name + "'");

            var myUrl = '@Url.Action("JobSelected", "Earth")';
            var newUrl = myUrl + '?jobNumber=' + myEntity.name.replace(/ /g, "");
            var newUrl2 = newUrl.replace("HTI#", "");
            var newUrl3 = newUrl2.substr(0, newUrl2.indexOf("-"));

            window.location.replace(newUrl3);
```

Controller code;

```
        <ActionName("JobSelected")>
    Function JobSelected() As ActionResult
        Dim q As String = Request.Url.Query

        q = Replace(q, "?jobNumber=", "")
        Dim result = edRepository.GetEarthDataByHtiJobNumber(q).ToList()

        Return View("EarthData2", result)
    End Function
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page so `Return RedirectToActionPermanent("EarthData2", result)` is pointless - ajax calls never redirect.

Comment: You want to do a Redirection via an ajax call  ? Why ?  Why not directly go to the `JobSelected` action method in a normal browser HTTP GET request ?  You can pass the string as querystring like `jobSelected?jobSpec=something`

Comment: You can use `window.location.href=newUrlHere` to do a new GET request from your js code.

Comment: Hi & thanks for the replies. I figured out along the way that ajax is meant to stay on the same page (for client/server interaction w/o page reloads). That's why I was sure there must be a different way.

Comment: As for the 'RedirectToActionPermanent', I've never used that before and was simply trying to get the point across that I wanted to go back to the controller and have it fire up another view.  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reload the page contents while maintaining a presence on the index or starter page?

Answer (score 0):

Being new to posting on StackOverflow (long-time user, though), sorry I put my answer in an edit.

Here's the answer:
**JavaScript:**

```js
        var leftClickHandler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);

        leftClickHandler.setInputAction(function (action) {
            //reset visibility of selectionIndicator and infoBox
            viewer.selectionIndicator.viewModel.selectionIndicatorElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-infoBox')[0].style.visibility = "visible";

            var pickedObject = viewer.scene.pick(action.position);
            //don't do anything if we didn't click on an object
            if (!Cesium.defined(pickedObject)) { return; }

            //don't do anything if it's not the entity we care about
            //if (entity !== pickedObject.id) { return; }

            //if this is the entity we care about, hide the selectionIndicator and infoBox
            viewer.selectionIndicator.viewModel.selectionIndicatorElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementsByClassName('cesium-infoBox')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";

            var myEntity = pickedObject.id;
            //alert("'" + myEntity.name + "'");

            var myUrl = '@Url.Action("JobSelected", "Earth")';
            //The following is just clean-up code dealing with myEntity.name
            //Take out the spaces, and add the Query question and equals sign
            var newUrl = myUrl + '?jobNumber=' + myEntity.name.replace(/ /g, "");
            //Take out the leading, unwanted header
            var newUrl2 = newUrl.replace("HTI#", "");
            //Take out the trailing text, after the job #
            var newUrl3 = newUrl2.substr(0, newUrl2.indexOf("-"));
            //Redirect to the new page url and fire it up
            window.location.replace(newUrl3);

        }, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

Controller function;

```
        <ActionName("JobSelected")>
    Function JobSelected() As ActionResult
        Dim q As String = Request.Url.Query

        q = Replace(q, "?jobNumber=", "")
        Dim result = edRepository.GetEarthDataByHtiJobNumber(q).ToList()

        Return View("EarthData2", result)
    End Function
```

Thanks to everyone who viewed or participated!